# How to use subsequent terminal commands as input in current command using Python

Tags: python, linux

I need to run a bunch of terminal commands, so I am automating it using os.system(). I first must run a command that switches into a different terminal path, and I then want to use the subsequent commands in this new directory.

The issue I am having is that when I enter the new path, the python program stalls. I am able to manually enter commands. As soon as I exit it, my program resumes and runs the remaining commands.

What I am using:

```
os.system('Command_to_enter_new_path'; 'ls'; 'echo a')
```

Is there any way to force python to run the ls and echo command in the new path? My understanding is that the python program stalls because the 'Command_to_enter_new_path' will run infinitely. I am using Python 2.

Comment: how do you set new path? Do you use `cd new path`? If you use something different then it may wait for closing it and it will not work even if you run it directly in console - so it is not problem with Python but problem with your command.

Comment: `os.system()` creates a new process, and waits until it terminates. There is no way for such a subprocess to change its parent's current working directory (or set a variable etc). This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) anyway; if you want to run shell commands, why aren't you doing it in the shell?

Comment: I am not using cd. It is a tool-specific command (confd_cli) that opens a new command line interface. I essentially have a system and to change the parameters, I first have to run the tool-specific command as modifications can only be made through it.

Comment: I have to run shell commands from this new command line interface. I am also automating this process. That's why I am trying to figure out how to run the cli command and then use subsequent shell commands as input to it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had  a similar problem in the past, what worked for me was using:

```
os.system('{} && {}').format(command1, command2)
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: The semantics of `&&` are possibly wrong here; the OP seems to want `;` instead.

Comment: Is there a solution for python 2?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, but I looked around a bit and maybe try: ```os.system('Command_to_enter_new_path; ls; echo a')```
The difference being the whole input is in quotes as opposed to each command.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It opens the CLI, and I have to quit it to run the next command.